# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class php

Tags: php

I have been asked to continue to program the remaining of our company's management system using PHP, though I'm just new to it. while inputting the url, I received this: Cannot redeclare class SessionHandler in C:\xampp\htdocs\RMS\classes\session\SessionHandler.php on line 4

It has three (3) classes: Session.php, SessionHandler.php,SessionController.php

Please do check the whole code below:

**For SessionHandler.php**

http://pastebin.com/ziA2advz

**NOTE:**
I already did research the same issue I have, they said, use require_once. Since it's already coded, what else do you think is the reason for this problem? I'm very new to PHP, so please bear with me. Thanks

Comment: Could you please check if there is a class called "SessionHandler" in Session.php?

Comment: Please check my session.php http://pastebin.com/hEWSbT92

Comment: If you are using PHP 5.4 you should change class name SessionHandler

Comment: I changed it to MySessionHandler.php now. And still the same problem.

Comment: It is not enough only changing file name, you need to change class name as MySessionHandler in MySessionHandler.php

Comment: Yeah thanks.. I changed everything to MySessionHandler

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`SessionHandler`](http://php.net/SessionHandler) is now (since 5.4) a reserved class name, you can't use this name for your own classes.

Comment: since PHP is case-sensitive, can I use Sessionhandler instead? Thanks.

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes, PHP is not case sensitive. Even if it was, it would be a *very* bad practice to rely on that. You should use [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) instead.

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes I would opt for `MySessionHandler` though :)

Comment: Hello, I tried to change it, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes What did you change it for ?

Comment: I changed it to MySessionHandler.php

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes Sure but it is just the file name, it doesn't matter much, what you must change is a line in the file from `class SessionHandler` to `class MySessionHandler` of course you must also change this name everywhere it is used in your application code ...

Comment: Thanks, I changed everything to MySessionHandler. Now I got another set of errors. This require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:/xampp/htdocs/RMS/classes/session/SessionHandler.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\RMS\classes\navigation\LoginContentController.php on line 2

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes pretty obvious, edit `C:\xampp\htdocs\RMS\classes\navigation\LoginContentController.php` and change line 2 to require `MySessionHandler.php` instead of `SessionHandler.php`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15317/discussion-between-betty-barnes-and-yent)